# Using assumptions when calling Simplify from Collect

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am quite new to *Mathematica*, so please be patient ;)

I have a very long equation that I have to sort for powers of a variable called `e` and that I want to simplify. So I call

```
Collect[equation,e,Simplify]
```

But in the factors of `e^k` there are a lot of square roots and powers of variables, terms like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} g^{\frac{1}{2}}$, that don't get simplified unless I pass the assumption `g > 0` to `Simplify`. But how can I pass this assumption if `Simplify` is called from within `Collect`? Or is there a totally different way to achieve this?

Thx

Stefan

Comment: Try:  Simplify[Collect[equation, e], Assumptions -> g > 0]

Comment: You can replace `Simplify` with `Simplify[#, Assumptions -> g > 0] &` or use [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html).

Comment: @Karsten7. I tried that out but aborted the evaluation after one hour. When I runned Collect with Simplify before it took around 10 minutes. I solved the problem now with Assuming[g>0,Collect[equation,e,Simplify]]. Thanks for the fast answers!!!

Comment: You could post a part of your `equation` together with your solution to this problem and a comparison with the other approaches suggested as a self answer. You can use [`AbsoluteTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html) to quantify the computation time.